# How to force template function overload for boost::bind?

Tags: c++, templates, boost-bind, boost-function, overloading

I'm trying to create predicate for `std::find_if` by using `boost::bind` together with `boost::contains` (from boost/algoritm/string library). 
Following snippet shows two ways how I'm trying to accomplish this.

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        std::string s1("hello mom");
        std::string s2("bye mom");

        boost::function<bool (std::string, std::string)> f = &boost::contains<std::string, std::string>;
        std::cout << s1 << " contains " << "hello, " << std::boolalpha << f(s1, "hello") << std::endl;
        std::cout << s2 << " contains " << "hello, " << std::boolalpha << f(s2, "hello") << std::endl;

        boost::function<bool (std::string)> contain_hello = boost::bind(boost::contains<std::string, std::string>, _1, std::string("hello"));
        std::cout << s1 << " contains " << "hello, " << std::boolalpha << contain_hello(s1) << std::endl;
        std::cout << s2 << " contains " << "hello, " << std::boolalpha << contain_hello(s2) << std::endl;
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When compiling this code with g++ 3.4.5 I'm getting following output.

```
error: conversion from `<unresolved overloaded function type>' to non-scalar type `boost::function<bool ()(std::string, std::string), std::allocator<void> >' requested
error: no matching function for call to `bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, boost::arg<1>&, std::string)'
```

When I switch to `boost::icontains` which has only one overload everyting works fine.
I know how to solve similar situation when there are multiple overloads of non-template function. 
Can someone help me write this correctly? Or should I write my own compare function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to write `static_cast<bool(*)(const std::string&, const std::string&)>(&boost::contains<..>)` to resolve the overload.

Yes, this is a royal pain with templates and overloading. Libs written with OOP and overloading in mind are difficult to use with templates and boost::bind.

We all wait for C++0x lambda expressions, which ought to resolve things better.

Comment: Small correction (at least in g++ 3.4.5)
static_cast<bool (*)(const std::string&, const std::string&)>(boost::contains<..>).

Now it works perfectly. Thanks a lot for quick hint.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I've updated the answer with that. I've usually used this with member-function ptrs so my regular func-ptr syntax was a bit rusty, apparently. ;)

Comment: Your frankness on the PITA nature of templates and overloading is very reassuring. Before seeing that, I thought I must have been doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That code looks fine (correct + compliant) to me, and it compiles using Visual Studio 2008 (with Microsoft language extensions disabled).

Try using a more up to date version of gcc.

Comment: The problem is that in my production code I cannot use another compiler.

Comment: In such a case, rely less on template magic: write a wrapper function which just uses the boost-code, and pass the wrapper function as argument to `find_if`.

Comment: I understand perfectly that I can write my own functor/wrapper to do matching.
I just wanted to learn what I'm missing in my reasoning while writing this code.
Also I agree that code readability suffers when writing this as in accepted solution.